# I can't add two var together and i've verified that the two of those were number var and not string (Java Script)

Tags: javascript

I'm currently codding a discordbot and ive made a roll function and it's working amazingly but I wanted to add a bonus to it so I've modified it and now the total is always a NaN or instead of adding themselves my 2 number are just lining themselves (ex: 2 + 2 = 22(sorry for my bad english)).There the image of my code
        ***PS: i'm using Visual Studio***     [My code atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3ppV.png)

that's the code althought you can't run it since it's made for discord bot
***EDIT:***I've changed the code like you said but it still make a NaN when I use it in discord. The new code is updated      ***EDIT2*** Iv'e agin updated the code althought my var bonus IS a number var and not a string like ive said in the title and itstil not work the roll are made but the total = NaN.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
var prefix = ("*");


bot.on('message',(message) =>{
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (command === "roll") {
         var numbers = args[0].split("d");
         var rhs = numbers[0].split("+").map(Number);
         var nbdice = numbers.shift();  
         var dicetype = rhs[0];
         var bonus = 0
         bonus = rhs[1];
         var answer = "";
         var total = 0;
         for (var i = 0; i < nbdice; i++){
             var roll = (Math.floor((Math.random() * dicetype + 1)));
             total += roll;
             answer += "I got a " +  roll + "\n";
         }
         total += Number(bonus);
         answer += "The total is " + total;
         message.channel.send(answer);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please add your actual code, instead of an image of your code

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO!
Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns an array of strings like this `["2", "3", "52"]`.

*Your code is doing this*

```js
let numbers = "2+2";
let rhs = numbers.split('+');
console.log(rhs); // Array of strings
let bonus = rhs[0];
let total = 2; // Assume this was the result of your for-loop
console.log(total + bonus); // Actually, you're concatenating strings.
```

*What you need to do is convert to a number those strings*

```js
let numbers = "2+2";
let rhs = numbers.split('+');
console.log(rhs); // Array of strings
let bonus = rhs[0];
let total = 2; // Assume this was the result of your for-loop

console.log(total + +bonus); // Look at the plus symbol

// you also can use the function Number as follow Number(bonus);
console.log(total + Number(bonus)); 

// you also can use the function parseInt as follow parseInt(bonus);
console.log(total + parseInt(bonus, 10));
```

*And finally, you can execute the function [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) using that array of strings, and convert to number its elements*

```js
let numbers = "2+2";
let rhs = numbers.split('+').map(Number);
console.log(rhs); // Array of strings
let bonus = rhs[0];
let total = 2; // Assume this was the result of your for-loop
console.log(total + bonus);
```

Comment: On top of unary `+` and `Number` constructor, [`parseInt` is another option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (one which can handle non-base 10 numbers as well).